# Is there a resource of lots of human text?

Tags: text, markov

I just coded a Markov chain that talks based on learned data. I'd like a resource of a lot of text data online, but can't seem to find any (most sites like Wikipedia have a lot of junk, not plain text files).

Is there any site that would have a lot of text file that is suitable to test a Markov chain on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gutenberg.org might have some resources for you. For example, here's what appears to be a bunch of Moby Dick, in text file form.

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701.txt

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is just removing the tag from wikipedia, how about using source like this one that they remove the tag for you?

http://kopiwiki.dsd.sztaki.hu/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NLTK text corpora?

Comment: Aren't those usually just words, as opposed to full sentences?

Comment: They include many sentences, such as president speeches, books and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Enron Email Dataset: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/

It is also hosted on Amazon AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/enron-email-data/